# How to deal with Dynamically changing class names in HTML source code while automating using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, dynamic, selenium-webdriver

How to deal with Dynamically changing "class names" or "ids" in HTML source code while automating using Selenium WebDriver

[image: Like This]

**Example Application : GMAIL**

Comment: What have you tried so far?? and need to share HTML code here instead of screenshot..

Comment: Be more specific about what the issue is, what exactly you need to select.You could use parts/attributes that you know or that are not changing.For automation purpose it would be a good start to see if you can find any api that you can use.Also make sure that you can really use gmail for automation and you don't have any restrictions like you could be blocked if you are doing too many requests.

Answer (score 1):

The Selenium mechanism for locating elements (`org.openqa.selenium.By`) offers other methods of locating elements.

Example: name, partialLinkText, css selector, xpath selector, tagname, linkText.

This [tutorial from Selenium Easy](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/selenium-locators) contains some easy to understand examples.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the cell index then using XPath or cssSelector will solve the issue. Here in the above screenshot it is clear that the text "Wordpress" is in 5th cell of each table row/so you can use below XPath to get the particular cell.

```
List<WebElement> cellValue = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table/descendant::tr/following-sibling::td[5]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate `<span name="WordPress">WordPress</span>` element, You can locate this element using `By.name()` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.name("WordPress"));
```

Comment: but I guess the name will also change based on the content of  table cell.